# Why do I get an "sh: write error: Invalid argument" when configuring the current_trigger for an iio_sysfs_trigger?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi3, yocto, iio

I keep getting an `sh: write error: Invalid argument` when I try to configure the current_trigger for an iio device, which is for the mpu6050. I am using Yocto Kirkstone for an rpi3.

Here are the steps I take:

```bash
cd /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio_sys_fs_trigger
echo 0 > add_trigger
cd /sys/bus/iio/devices/trigger1 #trigger0 exists by default
cat name #gives sysfstrig0, as expected
cd /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0
echo sysfstrig0 > trigger/current_trigger
```

And then the last line is where I get the error.
By default, there exists a trigger0 named `mpu6050-dev0`. When I write to `trigger/current_trigger`, using the command `cat mpu6050-dev0 > trigger/current_trigger`, then no problem occurs. Just thought it might be something worth mentioning.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Trigger should be registered in the IIO subsystem. You can’t throw arbitrary names there if u understand how it works.

Comment: Right, I'm not sure how you got that I am using arbitrary names though based on the steps I put. Could you provide clarification? I assume it is registered through the command `echo 0 > add_trigger`.